# postgressql update table in loop and commit after every 10000 updates

Tags: postgresql

i have table A with keycol,col2,col3 and table B with other columns as well. want to update table B columns with values from table A. and commit for every 10k updates.  below is the query i'm trying to run but want to use a cursor and update every 10k.

```
UPDATE b
SET 
  column2 = a.column2,
  column3 = a.column3
FROM a
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to have a way to understand which records are not yet updated (and perhaps to add a partial index with corresponding condition, to speed up your updates).

I assume that it is `b.column2 is null` (records with `b.column2 is null` are not yet updated).

In this case, your query might be:

```
update b
set column2 = a.column2, column3 = a.column3
from a 
where
  a.id = b.id
  and b.id in (
    select id
    from b
    where column2 is null
    order by id
    limit 10000
  )
;
```

Index to speed it up:

```
create index i_b_tmp on b using btree(id) where column2 is null;
```

If you want to run a bunch of UPDATEs manually, just open psql, execute your 1st UPDATE and then type `\watch 0.1` – it will repeat your query every 0.1 seconds.

Comment: i'm looking like a cursor increment by 1

Comment: what if i want to update a single table and commit for every 10k records?
like update b
set column2 = '', column3 ='' where column4='dummy' limit 10k.
i want to use something like limit but can't use it is there any alternate for it?

Comment: See my query, update with sub-select, this is the way how to limit your update